# Set editor presets by user group in TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have created a custom editor preset in TYPO3 10.4.

It works well if I added it to each page in `Page TSconfig` like this:

```
RTE {
  default {
    preset = custom_preset
  }
}
```

But I would like to add it to certain backend user groups. However, adding this typoscript to `Backend user > backend user groups > Options > TSconfig` doean't work.

How can I do this?

Thank toy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this is not possible. `RTE` is only a key for [Page TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/Rte.html), but not for [User TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/UserTsconfig/Index.html)

Configuring the RTE *per user/group* will lead to problems if another user/group with fewer functions later edits the content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
So is there another way to limit some users editor preferences?

Thing is, some of my users are not very experinced while others are. We would like to keep the backend interface for  inexperienced users as simple as possible.

Comment: The per user/group configuration stays problematic. Maybe you can focus on single fields/CEs and simplify RTE configurations for all users. If there are only a few CE types where advanced editors are using RTE heavily, maybe you can create an "advanced" version of these CE-types (e.g. CE "Text w/image" and "Andvanced Text w/image")

Comment: Yes, ok. Thank you for taking the time to post an answer.